# Distributed System Topology

Tags: c#, p2p, distributed-system, dht

Trying to implement an electronic voting system as a college project and just faced the most important step towards my aim < the system architecture >

Multi-Server/Multi-Client , MUST really be reliable to the point of about 80 million clients are online , It also MUST permit new server joining to support the voting process , Its output will be statistics & reports so that it MUST allow me gathering information at any time , Supporting encryption , hashing , digest acks , .. etc

My aim is just to support lots of clients without central point of failure then make client fount the suitable server(s) to authenticate & vote
Suitable server(s) depends on 2 criteria  :

- Server distance priority
- Server load priority

First criteria used Initially only , Both are used during voting process

After searching samples around my project found 6 solutions   :

- Dynamic DNS server in between servers & clients
- Web Farm Load Balancing Dispatcher in between clients & servers
- Serverless p2p cloud of servers , client join as the server of p2p using PNRP to get list of servers
- Serverless/State-Server p2p cloud of servers , client connects to state server to get list of servers
- Servers tree down from main server
- DHT network & database system

From my point of view last solution was the suitable as there isn't any bottle neck point of failure , this leads me start searching an out of box DHT library or full distributed system to be integrated in my application or just reinvent the wheel & implement the whole thing from scratch !!

Questions :
- Did i choose the right solution ?
   If YES , Please point me to the right route leads to an out of box [ .NET ] library or system !
   If NO , Please point me to the suitable [ .NET ] solution even that I didn't mention it in my 6 solutions !

Regards ,

Comment: Hi Ahmed, please remove the wpf tag. This post doesnt seem related to windows presentation foundation.

Comment: Define "the right solution."  Since it's a just college project, are you highly concerned about security (being able to verify that the election was not fixed)?  I think that will be the most difficult/important part: but as far as I'm aware, there's currently no solution to this problem that doesn't come at some unreasonable cost of convenience.

Comment: Oh, what an example of an overkill question, type similar to 'want to get to the moon, where do I start?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NChord](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nchord/) could get you started without having to start from scratch and probably will be good enough for an academic project.